# Является ли предложение сложным? (2)

Tags: синтаксис

**Таня и Маша вышивали.**
Сложное ли это предложение?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 2):

Это простое предложение, осложненное однородными подлежащими Таня и Маша.